# Como truncar una linea o hacer un salto de linea dependiendo del ancho de linea del terminal

Tags: linux, bash, script

Buenas tardes dispongo de un código el cual me muestra unas determinadas Lineas de colores como un linea de tiempo, el problema es que cuando llega al final del terminal se baja y se desbarata todo, quiero tener el control del ancho del terminal para que cuando lleguen los datos al ancho máximo del terminal, este haga dos saltos de linea, os enseño en una foto lo que me pasa.[image: quiero que en la barra de tiempo y memoria cuando detecte el ancho de la terminal salte y así quede limpio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder hacer un salto de línea primero has de saber que tamaño tiene la terminal.

Esto  lo puedes saber con el comando `tput cols`.

Fuente:
[StackOverflow - How do I find the width & height of a terminal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263900/8853552)